# Как хэширует пароль wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, хеширование

Хочу сделать на своем сайте хэширование пароля, как делает wordpress, чтобы на выходе получался хэш по типу: $P$B...
Но не совсем понимаю, какой там алгоритм, как вордпресс солит пароль и т.д.?
Как я понимаю, для создания хэша используются эти соли и ключи:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    
define('NONCE_KEY',        
define('AUTH_SALT',        
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   
define('NONCE_SALT',
```

Comment: В конфиге соли. [генератор](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/). Тебя это интересует?

Comment: Про конфиг понятно, а которая из них солит пароль и где вообще сам скрипт хэширования?

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php - ты про это спрашиваешь?

Answer (score 0):

Для создания хеша используется функция

`$hash = wp_hash_password( 'мой пароль' );`

Для сравнения введённого пароля и хеша - функция

`wp_check_password( 'мой пароль', $hash );`

которая возвращает `boolean`.

Применяемый в ядре алгоритм - blowfish, с использованием солей и констант.